# Ionic : first loading of my android application is abnormally slow

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, loading

the first loading of my android application is abnormally slow, if someone has already encountered this problem, I already try removing all plugins and reinstall them, and remove the android platform and create it again, the loading time does not changed, here are the messages that the application shows me

- Angular 2 is running in the development mode. Call enableProdMode() to enable the production mode.
- main.js:115328 Ionic Storage driver: cordovaSQLiteDriver
- plugins/cordova-sqlite-storage/www/SQLitePlugin.js:175 OPEN database: _ionicstorage
- plugins/cordova-sqlite-storage/www/SQLitePlugin.js:106 new transaction is waiting for open operation
- plugins/cordova-sqlite-storage/www/SQLitePlugin.js:179 OPEN database: _ionicstorage - OK
- plugins/cordova-sqlite-storage/www/SQLitePlugin.js:80 DB opened: _ionicstorage
- cordova.js:1223 deviceready has not fired after 5 seconds.
- main.js:7881 Native: deviceready did not fire within 2000ms. This can happen when plugins are in an inconsistent state. Try removing plugins from plugins/ and reinstalling them.
  **- main.js:7876 DEVICE READY FIRED AFTER 14273 ms**

And here is the list of my plugins

- Com.googlemaps.ios 2.1.1 "Google Maps SDK for iOS"
- Com.synconset.imagepicker 2.1.7 "ImagePicker"
- Cordova-plugin-compat 1.1.0 "Compat"
- Cordova-plugin-console 1.0.5 "Console"
- Cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview 2.1.0 "Crosswalk WebView Engine"
- Cordova-plugin-device 1.1.4 "Device"
- Cordova-plugin-file 4.3.2 "File"
- Cordova-plugin-file-transfer 1.6.2 "File Transfer"
- Cordova-plugin-filepath 1.0.2 "FilePath"
- Cordova-plugin-geolocation 2.4.1 "Geolocation"
- Cordova-plugin-googlemaps 1.4.0 "phonegap-googlemaps-plugin"
- Cordova-plugin-mauron85-background-geolocation 2.2.5 "CDVBackgroundGeolocation"
- Cordova-plugin-network-information 1.3.1 "Network Information"
- Cordova-plugin-splashscreen 4.0.1 "Splashscreen"
- Cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.2.1 "StatusBar"
- Cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.1 "Whitelist"
- Cordova-sqlite-storage 2.0.0 "Cordova sqlite storage plugin"
- Ionic-plugin-keyboard 2.2.1 "Keyboard"
- Onesignal-cordova-plugin 2.0.10 "OneSignal Push Notifications"

system information:

- Cordova CLI: 6.5.0
- Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-rc.4
- Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.17
- Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.7
- Ionic App Scripts Version: 0.0.47
- ios-deploy version: 1.9.0
- ios-sim version: 5.0.8
- OS: macOS Sierra
- Node Version: v7.2.1
- Xcode version: Xcode 8.2 Build version 8C38

Comment: What did you do to have the system show you these messages?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution, you have to put these line of code in main.ts of the application

```
import {enableProdMode} from '@angular/core';
enableProdMode();
```

and the flag --prod when you build your app

```
ionic build android --prod
```

now my DEVICE READY FIRED AFTER 2415 ms